# jQuery UI Dialog has unwanted vertical scrollbar in FF5

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to launch a jQuery UI dialog that contains an Iframe to a very simple html page. The page should not need scrollbars. In IE9 I don't get scrollbars, but in FF5 I get a vertical scrollbar. Here's the page that launches the dialog:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        iframe {width:100%; height:100%; border:0;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="" onclick="return showDialog()">Show the Dialog</a>
    <div id="dlg"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#dlg").dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true, width:400, height:300, resizable:false, title: "YO"});

        function showDialog()
        {
            $("#dlg").html('<iframe src="frame.htm" />').dialog("open");
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the simple frame.htm page that the IFrame displays:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        *    {margin:0; padding:0;}
        body { background:#EFF;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <p>I'm a paragraph</p>
    <div style="height:2px; background:#000;"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

?

So far the best I've been able to do is disable scrolling altogether by altering the jQuery UI CSS like this:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content { overflow: hidden; }
```

But I'd like to be able to use overflow:auto for if the content actually warrants a scrollbar.
Thanks very much for any help.

Answer (score 2):

The scrollbar disappears, once you set the iframe to `height: 95%`. As to why the dialog behaves like that, i would have to investigate further, but it does work for the moment

It seems to be caused by the dialog, not the iframe itself

Comment: Interestingly that doesn't work. Not sure if the scrollbar is on the iframe or its content. Either way I would rather there be a scrollbar if the iframe's content required one, but there not be one if it doesn't.

Comment: `$(element)[0].scrollHeight` gets the actual height of the content. If you check if that is larger than the viewport you could enable and disable the scrollbars as needed

Comment: In that case I was considering the iFrame as a viewport as well, since it's showing a complete page. As for the still existing scrollbars, I'm trying to reproduce that

Comment: I cannot reproduce that behaviour, so the scrollbar doesn't seem to come from the iframe

Comment: Yeah, I understand what you mean about the viewport. You can't reproduce the scrollbars using those exact 2 html files?

Comment: Nvm, could reproduce it on Chrome 12 and FF5 now, working on it

Comment: Yeah, shrinking the iframe height removes the scrollbar. I'm just concerned about that causing content to possibly be clipped on IE9 since it doesn't seem to have this quirk.

Comment: Well I'm thinking I could end up w/ a situation where now IE9 has the scrollbar because I've removed some of its height.